# SQLiteException near "(" syntax error code 1

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I don't get what I am missing. already tried using sql validators and they keep saying it is fine.

this is the part of the code that is causing the issue. before that I am creating the database and a table like this and it works.

```
AtividadesDAO.database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
                + BancoHelper.BANCO_TABELA_USUARIO_NOME + " ( "
                + BancoHelper.BANCO_COLUNA_ID + " INTEGER , " 
                + BancoHelper.BANCO_COLUNA_NOME + " varchar(50) , "
                + BancoHelper.BANCO_COLUNA_SENHA + "varchar(50));");
```

any ideas?

Comment: What's the value of `BancoHelper.BANCO_TABELA_USUARIO_NOME` ?

Comment: here you go: public static final String BANCO_TABELA_USUARIO_NOME = "Usuarios";

Comment: can you place whole class ?

Comment: just delete this question .. you forgot space before second varchar(50) ... just check full stacktrace to find an error ... i'm pretty sure that you have `senhavarchar(50));` at the end

Comment: All the variables are final an not null?

Comment: I don't think I can post almost 700 lines of code. what can I give you so you can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the query is made in android using SQLite, it should look more like this:

```
AtividadesDAO.database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "
                + BancoHelper.BANCO_TABELA_USUARIO_NOME + " ( "
                + BancoHelper.BANCO_COLUNA_ID + " integer primary key, " 
                + BancoHelper.BANCO_COLUNA_NOME + " text, "
                + BancoHelper.BANCO_COLUNA_SENHA + " text);");
```

If not working, please provide the error that occured so we can try and find a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be missing a space in the last line:

Try changing

```
+ BancoHelper.BANCO_COLUNA_SENHA + "varchar(50));");
```

to

```
+ BancoHelper.BANCO_COLUNA_SENHA + " varchar(50));");
```